# Plotting Using Curve on a Log-Log Plot in R

Tags: r

I am a PhD student studying allometric scaling in bull kelp and I have been trying to use the code below to add a regression line and a predicted slope line (slope=1) to my log-log plot of unlogged data and while R will "run" the code, the appropriate lines don't show up on my plot. I think it's a problem with the log scaling, ideally I'd like it to look more like a traditional log plot (axes with scale of 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000) but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that in R. I've included the data I am working with, I'd appreciate any help that you can provide!

> ```
> stipelengthcm - 1065.0  959.0  925.0  757.0  722.0  663.0  559.0  550.0  550.0  518.0  400.0  379.0 370.0  365.0  363.2  351.8  323.2  306.8  290.0  260.0  251.0  251.0  249.0  242.0 240.0  229.0  220.0
>
> bulbwidthcm -10.0 16.0  7.8 10.0 10.0  8.5  5.0  6.0  6.0  4.6  4.4  5.6  5.0  7.0  4.2  4.4  5.4  5.4 5.6  6.0  4.0  3.8  4.6  5.0  4.6  5.5  5.4
> ```

```
library(lmodel2)
regrlogkelp<-lmodel2(log(stipelengthcm)~log(bulbwidthcm), data=logkelp, nperm=99)
regrlogkelp

plot(stipelengthcm, bulbwidthcm, log="xy", xlab = "Stipe Length (cm)", ylab = "Bulb Width (cm)", pch = 1, col = "black")
curve(exp(regrlogkelp$regression[3,2]) * x^(regrlogkelp$regression[3,3]), add = T)
var < -(mean(bulbwidthcm)/exp(regrlogkelp$regression[3,2]))^(1/regrlogkelp$regression[3,3])
curve((x^2)*(mean(bulbwidthcm)/var^2), add =T, lty = "dashed")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in R base graphics or `ggplot2`.  Let's try `ggplot2`.

Let's say that your data is in `logkelp` and your regression is in `regrlogkelp`.

First make the predictions from your model.

```
#make predicted values
logkelp$logcurve1 <- regrlogkelp$regression[3,2] + 
log(bulbwidthcm)*regrlogkelp$regression[3,3]
```

Load `ggplot2` and ask for points and the prediction line.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=logkelp) +

#plots the points
geom_point(aes(x=bulbwidthcm, y=stipelengthcm)) +

#draws the prediction line; note that y here is exponentiated and matches your expression
geom_line(aes(x=bulbwidthcm, y=exp(logcurve1))) +

#put the x axis on the log scale and designate where tick marks will be
scale_x_log10(breaks=seq(0,20, by=1)) +

#put the y axis on the log scale and designate where tick marks will be
scale_y_log10(breaks=seq(0,2000, by=100)) +

#change from the default ggplot2 style
theme_bw(base_size = 15)
```

[image]

You can change the axis labels and colors if you'd like.  If you want to do confidence bands, take a look at `geom_ribbon()`

I think why your plot wasn't showing up was because the results of your `curve()` statement was far above your plotting area for your points.  R was executing it but you would have to change the scale to see it.  You are mixing `exp()` and `log()`.  It's also confusing because X and Y were swapped between your regression and your graph.

This is actually where R was plotting your results from `curve()`:

```
plot(stipelengthcm, bulbwidthcm, log="xy", 
xlab = "Stipe Length (cm)", ylab = "Bulb Width (cm)", pch = 1, col = "black", 
ylim=c(1,100000))
```

[image]